# Is Scrapy compatible with Python 3.8 on ubuntu?

Tags: scrapy

While i am try to install scrapy on ubuntu mechine using
`**pip install scrapy**` 
it's not going to workout.
can anyone suggest us?

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

Comment: try pip3 instead of pip

Comment: i tried it also . Thanks for replay

Comment: are you using venv?

Comment: yes i am using venv

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html), it was mentioned that to install scrapy in a venv on ubuntu based os, we need to install these dependencies `sudo apt-get install python3 python3-dev python3-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev`